# Notepad++ XML how can I tag e-mail addresses using regular expression across multiple files?

Tags: xml, notepad++

I have a large number of XML files that contain e-mail addresses. Using Notepad++ I wish to wrap all these e-mail addresses in `<email></email>` tags. I can find the e-mail addresses using a regular expression:

```
(\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}\b)
```

But how can I use Notepad++'s "replace in all opened documents" function (which I guess would be handy for this) to automatically wrap all the e-mail addresses?

So that for instance this

```
Write to us at johndoe@example.com or alternatively janedoe@example.com.
```

becomes

```
Write to us at <email>johndoe@example.com</email> or alternatively <email>janedoe@example.com</email>.
```

and this across several 100's of XML files at once?

Comment: Regex for email is not that simple, Please, have a look at these sites: TLD list: https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db ; valid/invalid addresses: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Examples ; regex for RFC822 email address:  http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains

Answer (score 0):

Just to answer my own question should other people stumble upon this, what I needed to do was to replace:

```
(\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}\b)
```

with

```
<email>\1</email>
```